# Unittesting class based view

Tags: django

How do I test a class based view with given url parameters?

The django documentation seems rather lacking when talking about class Based View testing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what your question is. If you use the test client, e.g. `response = self.client.get('/my-url/param1/param2/'`, then it doesn't matter whether the view is class-based or function-based.